# pdf see current line ruler

Tags: pdf, accessibility, acrobat

I'm looking for accessibility tool , to make it easier to read pdf's.

In short, it should be possible to easily see which line is being read ( a bit like a ruler,when it comes down to text ), to avoid losing the line that is being read.

I was wondering if anyone knows any solution for this , for example a plugin for Adobe Acrobat Reader, etc...

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a plug-in for Acrobat Reader.  You may want to look at ZoomText or ClaroRead. Of course these only work if the PDF has text, but not images of text.

A low tech solution would be to open a Notepad doc and size it how you need. If you are on Win7 you could do this with sticky notes.

Comment: While this is very useful, I want to clarify that I'm not really looking for something to read text out loud, but instead to show where I'm reading ( a visual help to show where I'm currently reading, so I don't lose the line ). Still, thanks for the information

Comment: I kind of assumed that. The only type of programs that tell you were you are are speech output or maginification programs.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I've used is to convert the PDF to HTML and then run a server with it. This is fairly simple to accomplish using Live Server in VScode.

In the Chrome browser, we may then use accessibility extensions, such as ReadingBuddies, that have reading ruler functions.

Otherwise consider,

1. Use a PDF reader that has a built-in reading ruler feature, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader DC or Foxit Reader.
2. Use a PDF reader that allows you to add a reading ruler as an annotation, such as Xodo PDF Reader.
3. Use an online tool that allows you to view PDFs with a reading ruler, such as Smallpdf's PDF Reader.
4. Use a screen ruler tool, such as the one offered by How-To Geek, to measure the PDF on your screen.